# Django изменения данных через модели

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Подскажите, какой из вариантов, будет более производителен, правилен и рабочим

У меня есть две таблицы. В таблице Book я создаю запись и хочу что бы при её создании она автоматически создавала запись в классе Store - это я реализовал через переопределение метода Save.
А вторым действием, когда в таблице Store поле stock = 0, тогда в таблице Books поле is_available = False. Но для такого случая, мне придётся в методе Save добавлять новую переменную и передавать её.

файл Book/book.py

```
from store.models import *
    
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    is_available = models.BoleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)

    def save(self, available=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if available 
            new_bookStore = Store(
                book_id = self,
                store=1
            )
            new_bookStore.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

файл Store/store.py

```
import Book.Books as book_mod
class Store(models.Model):
    book_id = models.ForeignKey('Book.Books', blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    store = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    stock = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=None)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if store == 0:
            change_book = book_mod.Books.objects.filter(id=self.book_id).first()
            change_book.is_available = False
            change_book.save(available=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Второй вариант навесить на таблицу Book триггер в бд, который будет при появлении новой записи сразу создавать новую запись в таблице Store. И второй триггер на таблицу Store, который будет проверять значение Stock и в случае если оно = 0, менять в таблице Book значение is_available на False.

И третий вариант, если я не ошибаюсь, можно сделать через drf и сериализаторы. При котором когда создаётся запись в Books можно сразу принимать второй сериалайзер для Store.

Подскажите, какой вариант мне лучше использовать для данной задачи или возможно у Вас есть свои варианты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется у вас нарушена логика создания `Store`, ведь при каждом сохранении `Book` c `available` будет создаваться новая запись в Store.
Логичней было бы сделать так:

1. Сделать сигнал `post_save` для Book, и при `created` пытаться создать новую запись Store через `Store.objects.get_or_create(book_id=instance)`.
2. Сделать сигнал `post_save` для Store, и при `store=0` выполнять `Book.objects.filter(pk=self.book_id).update(is_available=False)`

Такую же логику можно реализовать и в методах `save()` у моделей.